# OSGI Bundle Error - ojdbc6.jar

Tags: java, jdbc, osgi-bundle, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I am trying to convert my ojdbc6.jar into a bundle as mentioned in the steps here

http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/deploy_osgi/DeployJar-Convert.html

Unfortunately I am getting an error as below.  Kindly help

One error

> 1 : Unresolved references to [com.sun.security.auth.module,
>   javax.resource, java x.resource.spi, javax.resource.spi.endpoint,
>   javax.resource.spi.security, oracle .i18n.text,
>   oracle.i18n.text.converter, oracle.ons, oracle.security.pki] by clas
>   s(es) on the Bundle-Classpath[Jar:OJDBC_PLUGIIN_1.0.0.jar]:
>   [oracle/jdbc/connect or/OracleResourceAdapter.class,
>   oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleConnectionCacheManager$1. class,
>   oracle/net/ano/AuthenticationService.class,
>   oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleRuntim
>   eLoadBalancingEventHandlerThread$1.class,
>   oracle/sql/converter/CharacterSetMetaD ata.class,
>   oracle/jdbc/connector/OracleManagedConnection.class, oracle/jdbc/conn
>   ector/OracleManagedConnectionMetaData.class,
>   oracle/jdbc/connector/OracleConnect ionRequestInfo.class,
>   oracle/jdbc/connector/OracleManagedConnectionFactory.class ,
>   oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleFailoverEventHandlerThread$1.class,
>   oracle/sql/converte r/CharacterConverterFactoryOGS.class,
>   oracle/sql/converter/Orai18nCharacterSetMe taData.class,
>   oracle/jdbc/connector/OracleConnectionManager.class, oracle/jdbc/c
>   onnector/OracleLocalTransaction.class,
>   oracle/jdbc/driver/PhysicalConnection.cla ss,
>   oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleFailoverEventHandlerThread.class,
>   oracle/jdbc/pool/Or acleRuntimeLoadBalancingEventHandlerThread.class,
>   oracle/sql/converter/I18Charac terConvertersWrapper.class]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have enabled dynamic import in my bundle and it worked.

Comment: That is all we have to do is add this statement in the Manifest  `DynamicImport-Package: *`

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed that with the folowing methods:

1) Wrap oracle jdbc library into local maven repository

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/home/mike/ojdbc7.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

2) Wrap oracle jdbc library from local maven to OSGi bundle

```
osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:com.oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2.0
```

3) In the pom.xml of my own OSGi bundle:

```
<Import-Package>oracle.jdbc.driver,*</Import-Package>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try installing the JAR as-is using the wrap handler

```
install wrap:file:/path/myfile.jar
```

Comment: I have created it as wrap:file.   But I am getting an error as java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver not found by <ProjectName>

Comment: Check that the oracle jar you installed has an Export-Package statement for the "oracle.jdbc.driver" package and your other bundle has an Import-Package to match.