# Create a feature with Oracle Drivers (ojdbc6)

Tags: jdbc, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, fuseesb, fabric8

I want to create a feature with all my oracle dataSources so I that can add them to a fabric profile.

I managed to access my dataSources in a non fabric installation of JBoss Fuse by deploying oracle drivers directly to the deploy folder, and then creating all my dataSources in a bundle.

The problem is that when I include both dataSources and ojdbc6.jar in a single bundle, JBoss Fuse can't create my Oracle Connector class:

`Unable to resolve 317.2: missing requirement [317.2] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=oracle.jdbc.pool)`

I've tried to drag-drop the drivers directly in the deployment section of a new profile in the management console and installing the jar as a maven jar with the same result.

When I install the drivers with osgi:install mvn:... it throws the same error.

```
[ 321] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   80] mvn:com.oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.4
```

Maybe I'm wrapping the jar wrong, I used this solution to install the jar in Maven [OSGI Bundle Error - ojdbc6.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015281/osgi-bundle-error-ojdbc6-jar)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the Oracle drivers with the pom in [this git repo](https://github.com/section6nz/ojdbc6-osgi) and then defining the bundle in the feature like this:

```
<bundle>wrap:mvn:com.oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.4</bundle>
```

worked for me.